# Resources for old vintage (1960's and older) photography for use?

Tags: images, photography, resource-recommendations, vintage

I've been searching for some good resources for old photos for use in designs. I've checked out the Flickr Commons, but I'm wondering if there were alternative sources I don't know about for copyright-free photography. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Googling "Royalty Free Vintage Photography" came up with a number of decent websites. http://nos.twnsnd.co/ looks like it might have something. Getty has an entire "[Retrofile Collection](http://www.gettyimages.com/search/2/image?family=creative&phrase=images&license=rm&excludenudity=false&collections=RET)."